# How to set correctly from CMAKELIST the visual studio platform toolset to v100?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, cmake

****Hello to everyone,

Because of the error messages , I will paste here, the post might look long but it’s really short!!
I am working on a windows 7(64 bits), where I have to generate a c++ visual studio IDE with cmakeusing a library compiled with visual studio 10. But I want to work with visual studio 12! I have both visual studio 10 and 12 on my computer!

```
When I try to compile using the CMAKE-Gui setting Visual Studio 10 (Win64) as compiler:****

...

testCCompiler.c
1> 
1> testCCompiler.c
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.84

CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project. Call Stack (most recent call first): CMakeLists.txt:16 (project) Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! See also ...
```

**When I try to compile using the CMAKE-Gui setting Visual Studio 10(this one is probably 32bits) as compiler:**

```
 testCCompiler.c


LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file
invalid or corrupt





1>Build FAILED.
...
```

**When I compile using Visual Studio 12(Win64), I get this error:**

```
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Visual Studio 12 Win64". CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set. You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: U:/Develop/CMAKE Builds/ADTF_PLUGINS_DATAFUSION111/CMakeFiles/2.8.12.2/CMakeCCompiler.cmake
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: U:/Develop/CMAKE Builds/ADTF_PLUGINS_DATAFUSION111/CMakeFiles/2.8.12.2/CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake
Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

**Only when I used  the cmake setting Visual Studio 11(Win64) did it work, but then when I opened the solution in visual studio 12 and comlpiled there were a compiler conflict:**

```
error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1600' doesn't match value '1700' in cBaseFusionViewer.obj   U:\Develop\CMAKE Builds\[…]
```

I can change manually in visual studio the TOOLSET property from v110 to v100 but I’d like to do this automatically from cmake. I have tried the following lines without success:

```
set compiler visual studio 10

set(PLATFORM_WIN32_MSVC_TOOLSET v100 CACHE STRING "MSVC Platform toolset" FORCE)

set(PLATFORM_SUFFIX "-v100" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
```

**Herefore I have following two questions:
-   Why is there a listed working compiler Visual Studio 11(win64) in cmake when I have installed Visual Studio 12 and that one fails by generation of the solution with cmake!???
-   How do I correctly set the toolset compiler v100 in cmake!???**

Thanks for your support in advance!!

Comment: Visual Studio 10 = Visual Studio 2010. Visual Studio 11 = Visual Studio 2012. Visual Studio 12 = Visual Studio 2013. Yes, the naming is confusing as hell. It has been clarified for CMake 3.0.

Comment: ok! I am stupid, I should have seen it actually , it's just the difference between version and year! But I am still stucked with the toolset problem though!! Thanks for the answer!

Comment: You should not mess with the toolchain and compiler variables from within the CMake script. The idea is that *the user* sets those to whatever they want to compile with (from the command line or via the `cmake-gui`), and your CMake script just reacts accordingly (in the worst case aborting with an unsupported toolchain error).

Comment: I understand  ComicSansMS, but that is in my case not necessary since, the end product wont allow or need the change of that option! It is merely a static option! I could as well i guess just use visual studio 2010. It's really just to be able to use visual studio 2012 on my development pc. the end product is used as a plugin within another simulation environment which want extend to these options from the command without!

Comment: I understand ComicSansMS, but that is in my case not necessary since, the end product wont allow or need the change of that option! It is merely a static option! I could as well i guess just use visual studio 2010. It's really just to be able to use visual studio 2012 on my development pc. The end product is used as a plugin within another simulation environment which will not extend to these options from the command window!